# Improving The Performance Of MSChart Toolip?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, mschart

> Improving The Performance Of MSChart Toolip?

We are using MSChart on an ASP.net 3.5 web application and noticing significant slowness from enabling tooltips. the performance of drawing a chart is very slow. Since I'm using large dataset to draw a graph.The chart output is JPEG, and contains in total more than 500 data points.

```
            chart.DataSource = dv;
            chart.Series.Invalidate();
            chart.Series.SuspendUpdates();

            chart.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "Time_Value";
            chart.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "Total1";
            chart.Series["Series2"].XValueMember = "Time_Value";
            chart.Series["Series2"].YValueMembers = "Total_thru";
            chart.Series["Series3"].XValueMember = "Time_Value";
            chart.Series["Series3"].YValueMembers = "Total2";
            chart.Series["Series4"].XValueMember = "Time_Value";
            chart.Series["Series4"].YValueMembers = "Total2_thruput";
            chart.Series["Series5"].XValueMember = "Time_Value";
            chart.Series["Series5"].YValueMembers = "BAWA_Total";
            chart.Series["Series5"].LegendText = "Count";
            chart.Series["Series5"].IsVisibleInLegend = true;
            chart.DataBind();

            chart.Series["Series2"].LegendText = "Throughput1";
            chart.Series["Series2"].IsVisibleInLegend = true;
            chart.Series["Series1"].LegendText = "Count1";
            chart.Series["Series1"].IsVisibleInLegend = true;
            chart.Series["Series3"].LegendText = "Count2";
            chart.Series["Series3"].IsVisibleInLegend = true;
            chart.Series["Series4"].LegendText = "Throughput2";
            chart.Series["Series4"].IsVisibleInLegend = true;

            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = -90;
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Trebuchet MS", 6.00F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 600;
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsStartedFromZero = true;
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.TitleFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Trebuchet MS", 10.00F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.TitleFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Trebuchet MS", 10.00F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.TitleFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Trebuchet MS", 10.00F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);

            chart.Legends[0].Docking = Docking.Bottom;
            chart.Legends[0].IsDockedInsideChartArea = false;
            chart.Legends[0].TableStyle = LegendTableStyle.Wide;
            chart.Legends[0].Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            chart.Series[0].ToolTip = "#VALY{d} (#VALX)";
            chart.Series[1].ToolTip = "#VALY{d} (#VALX)";
            chart.Series[2].ToolTip = "#VALY{d} (#VALX)";
            chart.Series[3].ToolTip = "#VALY{d} (#VALX)";
            chart.Series[4].ToolTip = "#VALY{d} (#VALX)";
```

Answer (score 0):

You havent shown the code for the ToolTip. A ToolTip could also show a constant string as well. Do you mean to show the value of the DataPoint in the Tooltip? What is `chart.Series["Series5"].XValueMember = "Time_Value";` this series for? Its YValueMember is not set. Besides the question is not clear, could you explain ?

Comment: I'm taking values from DB and binding into series and also for tooltip.